# Error: missing type specifier - int assumed. C++ does not support default int

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, templates

I wrote a sample class with template use. it's fairly simple:

```
template <class T>
class myClass
{
public:

    // construction, destruction
    myClass();
    virtual ~myClass();
    class Object
    {
    public:
        Object() { m_pNext = NULL; m_pPrev = NULL; }
        ~Object() {}

        T        m_Value;

        Object*  m_pNext;
        Object*  m_pPrev;
    };

public:

    // accessor functions
    Object* Beginning();

private:

    Object* m_pBegin;
    Object* m_pEnd;
    INT m_nCount;

};

template <class T> 
inline myClass<T>::Object* myClass<T>::Beginning()
{ return m_pBegin; }


template <class T>
inline myClass<T>::myClass()
{

}

template <class T>
inline myClass<T>::~myClass()
{

}
```

I use visual studio 2008, and here is the compile error

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  ...
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

the errors are linked to this line:

```
inline myClass<T>::Object* myClass<T>::Beginning()
```

Can anyone tell me what was wrong in this code?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have to say `typename myClass<T>::Object`. But why not write that oneliner inside the definition anyway?

Comment: Honestly, I don't get your question. Do you mean why not write those inline functions inside the class definition? If so, i dont know what is the difference, and please enlighten me.

Comment: The difference is a lot less writing, and the function will be declared `inline` implicitly: `Object * Beginning() { return m_Begin; }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change

```
template <class T> 
inline myClass<T>::Object* myClass<T>::Beginning()
{ return m_pBegin; }
```

to

```
template <class T> 
inline typename myClass<T>::Object* myClass<T>::Beginning()
{ return m_pBegin; }
```

because `myClass<T>::Object` is a dependent type.